# $_POST read out values in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

It is not possible to read out the $_POST variable with this code. Can you please give me a hint where the problem is? The condition block does not work.

When reading out the POST content from the Browser the values seem to be set and transfered.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
// select post operation
echo "post=".$_POST["action"];
if ($_POST["action"] == "add"){
    // insert and read out values from DB
    echo "add-".$_POST["action"];
    header("Location:".($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    unset($_POST);
} elseif ($_POST["action"] == "delete"){
    echo "add-".$_POST["action"];
    header("Location:".($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    unset($_POST);
}
else{
    echo "why else after submit.";
}
$_REQUEST = $_POST = $_GET = NULL;
?>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <form action="<? echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>      
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, you have a redirect right after the echo, so you probably don't have enough time to read it, as it reloads the page. Comment out the redirection code and check if it echos something.

Comment: It is very bad practice to do `unset($_POST);` and `$_REQUEST = $_POST = $_GET = NULL;`.

Comment: `$_POST` won't be filled in when you first open the page, only after you submit the form.

Comment: commented out but does not help

Comment: @FirstOne: it'd be configuration. PHP doesn't run with output buffering enabled by default. In most standard installs, OP's code would produce a "headers already sent" warning. Since there's no mention of such a warning/error, probably they're running with display_errors/error_reporting off.

Comment: Yeah, I reproduced it on my system, too. I've deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You never check if a POST was actually performed, so your `if()` chain ALWAYS executes. When you first hit the page, that loads it as a GET, therefore you get the `why else after submit` error.

You need something more like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
   ... check form submission, echo confirmation/errors, blah blah blah
}
... output html ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you redirect to an other page with

```
header("Location:".($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

actually you redirect to the same page so a brand new (same) page is served to you with an empty $_POST variable